# How do I plot with my axis label as time (in hrs, mins etc.)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using pylab in python to plot certain data. The data could range from a matter of a few minutes to hours, even days. I'd like to display it in a easy to understand format such as hours:mins, or days, hours:mins.

How do I do that using Matplotlib or pyplot?

Currently, I'm using time.time() as my time axis ticks. This is unintelligible to the ordinary person since it's a float that shows time passed since 1970 or so.

```
    currTime=time.time()
    pylab.xlim(startTime, currTime)
    #startTime comes from a data file
```

I'm aware how to get time in different formats, but I don't know how to set it to the axis since pylab.xlim() will only accept floats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `datetime` objects? Matplotlib should happily draw with them on the x axis.

For example:

```
import datetime

figure()
plot((datetime.datetime(1970,1,1), datetime.datetime(2000,1,1)), (0,1))
xlim(datetime.datetime(1980,1,1), datetime.datetime(1990,6,5))
```

Internally, the values used with matplotlib are days since 1st Jan 1, whereas time.time() gives the number of seconds since 1st Jan 1970.